# regular expression for in java

Tags: java, regex

I have following code to perform some regular expression on the string

```
public class RegexForPresto {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^M^M rawtostampedMsg^L 48^UT ");

    String candidateString = "^M^M rawtostampedMsg^L 48^UT 1338802566.906^EOH^name;

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(candidateString);
    String tmp = matcher.replaceAll("");

    System.out.println(tmp);
    }

    }
```

Instead of just getting

```
^EOH^name
```

I get following output when I execute

```
^M^M rawtostampedMsg^L 48^UT 1338802566.906^EOH^name
```

Also is it possible to remove "^EOH^" from the string so as to get only "name" as the output. I don't know how to remove the special character( "^"). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your circumflexions aren’t doing what you think they are there.

Comment: "^" is a special character for RegEx. You can se Pattern.quote() to match that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have not tested the code, I think this should work for you:

```
public class RegexForPresto {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("^M^M rawtostampedMsg^L 48^UT ")); // <-- This line is changed

    String candidateString = "^M^M rawtostampedMsg^L 48^UT 1338802566.906^EOH^name;

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(candidateString);
    String tmp = matcher.replaceAll("");

    System.out.println(tmp);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use this pattern

```
.*EOH.(.*)
```

then get the result from the first capture group like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class PatternTest {
    @Test public void testPatter() {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*EOH.(.*)");
        String candidateString = "^M^M rawtostampedMsg^L 48^UT 1338802566.906^EOH^name";
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(candidateString);
        if(matcher.matches()){
            String tmp = matcher.group(1);
            Assert.assertEquals("name", tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you trying to do. It seems like you want to treat the `ˆ` as a plain character. In that case you have to escape it in the regular expression with `\\ˆ`.

The `^` is a special character.

You may also want to try an online tester, such as [this one](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). It will be faster to test and it will explain more clearly what is being matched.

Comment: Instead of escaping special character with `\\`, I would rather suggest to use Pattern.quote()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: That works when all characters need to be escaped. It may solve this specific issue, but is not a generic solution. From past experience, it can cause problems down the road, when someone has to update the expression because it became a "real" regex. I prefer to start off with the escaped characters (but that betrays my age...).